# Analytic function in domain D and local max

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, proof-writing, analytic-functions

> For $f$ that is analytic on domain D, $|f(z)|$ has no local maximum within its domain of analyticity.

I have proven the result that $|f(z)|\leq$ max $|f(z+re^{it})|$ ($0\leq t\leq 2\pi$), and am trying to use it show that $|f|$ has no strict local maximum within its domain of analyticity by contradiction.

Is it just assuming that if there is a maximum say $f(z_0)$ then we can find a small enough r s.t. $f(z_0+re^{it})$ is still within the domain but bigger than $f(z_0)$? If so, I was wondering how can I write it down in a more rigorous way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Maximum Modulus Principle the fact that $f$ attains its maximum at an interior point of  some closed disk around $z$ implies that $f$ is a constant on the disk. Since the domain of $f$ is connected this implies that $f$ is  a constant throughout $D$.

Comment: thank you; so unless it is constant function, then it does not attain a peak in three dimension?

Comment: @jamesblack Yes, that is true.